# Apply mulitple functions to one column and send the result to two new columns

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I am wondering how I can apply multiple custom functions (like function1, function2) on one single column and get the results to two new columns.

```
import pandas as pd
  
# List of Tuples
matrix = [(1, 2, 3),
          (4, 5, 6),
          (7, 8, 9)
         ]
  
# Create a DataFrame object
df = pd.DataFrame(matrix, columns = list('xyz'), 
                   index = list('abc'))

>>> df
   x  y  z
a  1  2  3
b  4  5  6
c  7  8  9


>>> df_expected
   x  y  z  z_square  z_divide_by_3
a  1  2  3      6       1
b  4  5  6      36      2
c  7  8  9      81      3
```

Comment: Is there a reason this can't be done in 2 different operations?

Comment: Do you mean mulitple lines of `df['column'].apply`? I guess I could but I am just wondering if there's something less repeated. @dm2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `assign`:

```
df.assign(z_square=df['z']**2, z_divide_by_3=df['z']/3)
```

output:

```
   x  y  z  z_square  z_divide_by_3
a  1  2  3         9            1.0
b  4  5  6        36            2.0
c  7  8  9        81            3.0
```

Comment: df.assign(**{'z_square': df['z']**2, 'z_divide_by_3': df['z']/3})

Comment: @eroot163pi this doesn't really make a difference, this syntax is mostly useful when the assigned variable is not a valid python name (e.g. with spaces).